# How to hash a CAN message?

Tags: python, cryptography

I want to Hash a CAN message received from a vehicle. The following code written in Python is used to receive the CAN message(`dev.recv()`) from the vehicle and print the received message (`dev.send()`).I want to hash the CAN message present in `dev.recv()`function before sending the message using `dev.send()`.Is this possible? If so how can it be done?

```py
from canard.hw import socketcan

dev = socketcan.SocketCanDev(’can0’)
dev.start()
while True:
    f = dev.recv()
    dev.send(f)

`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hash"?

Comment: cryptographic hash function. It is used to convert a message to a fixed length  ciphertext

Comment: Hash does not convert a message to ciphertext. Which is exactly why I asked what you meant by it. Do you in fact want to encrypt the message? Or are you trying sign the message? Or something else? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to do something like this for an input like this "slcan0 123 [8] 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88" output should be a hash like this "38a2dbcf47db1d3026e89f6118d308f1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I am not sure what the data type is for `"f"`, the data you receive from the function `recv`.
- I am guessing that `SocketCanDev` is just a wrapper for the device, and `recv` acts very similar to the function, read().
- So, `"f"` in your code might be interpreted as an array of bytes, or chars.

> Hashing is done to an array of bytes, regardless of the format of the
>   string.

And, the result of the hashing does not depend on the input format or data type.
Therefore, in your case,

```
while True:
    f = dev.recv()
    result = (hashFunction)(f)
    dev.send(result) // result should in the data type that the function send can accept as a parameter
```

`(hashFunction)` can be replaced with an actual function from a hashing library, such as "hashlib".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for your comment. I edited and made changes. I now know about the backquote, thanks!

Comment: dev.send() accepts only CAN message format like 11 22 33 44 55 66 so how can I send the hashed message across the CAN bus?

Comment: You need to re-format the result so that it is sendable. If SHA1 hash is used, result would be an array of 16 bytes (128 bits). If CAN message should in format "11 22 33", you can transform it by concatenating the array values plus whitespace. Ex. message = array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + ... + array[15]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in cryptographic hashing, you should take a look at [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)

With it you should be able to hash the message and send the hash like this

```py
H = hashlib.new('sha256', message)
dev.send(H.digest())
```

If you want to still send the original message besides the hash, you could make two calls to `send`.